# Is it possible to create a fully custom Repository for Spring Data?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I am looking to create a fully custom Spring Data `CrudRepository` which would be backed by an external API service. Is this possible in the current Spring Data set-up?

Alternatively, should I look to wire-up my own solution with the standard Mvc or WebFlux controllers + service calls?

All my research points to requiring a standard database or dialect such as SQL, Redis, etc., rather than a fully custom Repository.

— EDIT: Adding more explanation on the ‘why’.

The Spring Data REST framework provides a range of nice, opinionated, ready-to-use solutions for making a backing repository behaviour more like a web service. I was hoping to tap into this by building a customised `@CrudRepository` that swaps the SQL queries for custom API calls.

Spring Data REST does not appear to pick up the `@CrudRepository` classes if a backing data source (as evidenced by a doc type, i.e. `@Entity` or `@RedisHash`) is not in the class path.

The alternative is to go for the ‘traditional’ `@Controller` -> `@Service` -> `@Repository` route is likely the simpler option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a repository implementation class by following: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-composable-repositories

And have it not perform database queries but instead call out to an external API instead via RestTemplate (Spring Mvc) or WebClient (Spring Webflux)

However I wouldn't recommend this, it sounds like a peculiar thing to do. Instead I would create a Service (class annotated with @Service) that is responsible for calling out to this external API.

Comment: Thank you! And a great question as to ‘why’.

The Spring Data REST framework provides a range of nice, opinionated, ready-to-use solutions for making a backing repository behaviour more like a web service. I was hoping to tap into this by building a customised `@CrudRepository` that swaps the SQL queries for custom API calls.

Spring Boot does not appear to pick up the `@CrudRepository` classes if a backing data source (as evidenced by a doc type, i.e. `@Entity` or `@RedisHash`) is not in the class path.

I will go the usual route - thanks!

Comment: I will leave this open for another day or two then pick this answer if no more responses. This is the cleanest route.

Comment: Yeah that is a good point for the above solution to work there would need to be a backing datasource.